# How to insert date datatype using SQL insert query

Tags: sql

```
insert into medicines (medicine_ id, name, formula, type, quantity, date_of_expiry, CPY_ID, USR_ID)
values (7153, 'ESOPAN', 'ESOMEPRAZOLE', 'capsule', 50, DATE'2023-12-12', 'PANACEA PHARMA', 2010);
```

What is problem with it?

Comment: What error you are getting? also mention the Database details.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Syntax issue in the script-

1. Additional space between column medicine_ id
2. Extra DATE in the VALUES part

You can try this adjusted code below-

```
INSERT INTO  medicines (medicine_id, name, formula, type, quantity, date_of_expiry, CPY_ID, USR_ID)
VALUES (7153, 'ESOPAN', 'ESOMEPRAZOLE', 'capsule', 50, '2023-12-12', 'PANACEA PHARMA', 2010)
```

Comment: now it is giving this error      ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: datatype of date_of_expiry is date

Comment: Then try with keeping DATE as earlier. Only remove space from medicine_ id

Comment: Your column name CPY_ID suggest its a Numeric field but you are providing value 'PANACEA PHARMA' to it. Is it expected?

Comment: create table companies
(
     company_name   varchar(30) not null,
     address         varchar(30) not null, 
    constraint cpy_pk primary key( company_name )
);

Comment: Then please check other columns data type and provided value. Error explains that some data mismatch are there.

Comment: all values are inserted in same datatype as explaned in table

Comment: No more clue :(